# Counting binary zero's until 1

Tags: python, python-3.x

Would like to count a binary value of integers until a 1 is reached. Then return an integer, not a list.

```
binary = bin(1)[2:].zfill(8)
# 00000001
zeros = [x for x in binary] # .. Count zeros... Until 1
print(zeros) # Expected 7 integer, not type <class 'list'> = 7 until 1
# ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1']
```

Input:
00000001

Expected Output:
7

Comment: Why would you expect `zeros = [x for x in binary]` to result in the integer value 7? It is clearly a list comprehension which creates a list, not an integer.

Comment: Could just do `zeros.count("0")`? Not really clear what other inputs to expect/account for.

Comment: Was trying to learn, I was trying to do many things such as. `MAP = sum((lambda x: int(x) == 0, binary))`

Comment: @blorgon your answer was correct, please post answer. So I may approve.

Comment: `len('00000001'.split('1', 1)[0])`

Comment: @blorgon Only possible alternative to the correct solution you provided, would be to continue counting until the next 1 if it had multiple 1's and 0's to return two integers. But this was not the question. Your comment answered correctly. That's if a different binary input was provided such as `00010001`, retuning 3, 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I guess I'll post my answer as a comment, as requested by OP.

First:

```py
zeros.count("0")
```

Of course, we could make this a bit more general. Consider any binary number, padded with zeros to some width:

```py
>>> b = f"{19:010b}"
>>> b
'0000010011'
```

You could then take this binary string and split it on `"1"`:

```py
>>> b.split("1")
['00000', '00', '', '']
```

Then find all counts of contiguous zeros:

```py
>>> [s.count("0") for s in b.split("1")]
[5, 2, 0, 0]
```

You could then filter out the counts of `0`, since those correspond to areas where there were contiguous `1` bits...

I dunno I feel like not enough information was given so this could really go in so many directions!

Comment: Thanks for the help, will approve after the time limit. Much appreciated. I knew it made a list, but you understood what I was going for.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: you we're spot on with your answer. Only alternative approach, besides solving my question. Was to adapt it like I said if you had a binary string of 00010001 to return, two integers of 3, 3. Which means 3 zeros before the first 1 at position 4 and other 3 until the second 1 at position 8. But that wasn't the original question. You got it right.

Comment: Yep, could easily `tuple(s.count("0") for s in b.split("1") if s)` which would give all nonzero counts of contiguous zeros in a binary string.